# Custom ToggleButton in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, togglebutton

I am working on a MvvmCross based android app. The app contains (among other things) a large number of ToggleButton(s). The buttons are added in .axml files. Their Checked property and Click event are bound to view-model properties. Since the Checked property of the each ToggleButton should reflect the state of some property on a application server, I don't want their checked state to be changed when the user clicks them, but only when the bound property on the view-model is changed. An example how this "special" toggle button should work: When the user clicks it, the "Checked" property of the button does not change only the ICommand to which the click event is bound to is invoked. The method invoked by the command in turn changes the value of the property on the view-model(if executed successfully). Extending a ToggleButton in WPF or Windows Forms to described functionality is easy but I don't know how to do that in android. Any ideas will appreciated.

Uroš

Comment: What have you tried so far? Implementing and extending controls in Android and their bindings in MvvmCross is straight-forward. For some examples, see N=18 and N=28 in http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com

Comment: Hi Stuart. I agree that implementing custom bindings in MvvmCross is straight-forward. I checked out the N=18 tuttorial and also found few of your answers here on stackoverflow. But I think my problem cannot be solved with custom binding since I am having problems with visual state of the ToggleButton. I also tried extending the ToggleButton and attaching the OnClickListener inside the override but I didn't get very far with it. I googled for articles explaining the topic but could not find anything releted to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. It seems it had to do something with the way I set up the bindings for my ToggleButton

MyToggleButton was implemented as:

```
public sealed class MyToggleButton : ToggleButton, View.IOnClickListener
{
    public MyToggleButton(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) 
        : base(context, attrs)
    {
        SetOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        Checked = !Checked;
    }
}
```

As you can see I just set the Checked property back to previous value when ever the user clicks the button. In the asmx I use the following block to add the button.

```
<controls.MyToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="Checked Value;Click ClickCommand" />
```

As it turns out the problem with described solution is that the OnClick(View v) method is not executed when the user clicks the button as long as the .axms file contains binding to Click event. I have no idea why that is so I would love any explanation. The workaround I used is to define custom event in the derived class, raise the custom event in the OnClick event handler and than bind to that event.

Uros