# Unexpected behavior caused by the MvvmCross bindings.

Tags: android, binding, mvvmcross

This post is based on a previous question I posted on stackoverflow. I found the solution to my problem, but I am posting this question becouse I suspect this is a bug in the MvvmCross platform. The question can be found on: [Custom ToggleButton in Xamarin.Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971224/custom-togglebutton-in-xamarin-android). To replicate the behavior follow this steps:

Extend the ToggleButton(I found this issue with toggle button but I guess it is the same with other UI elements) and create the listener for the click event:

```
public sealed class MyToggleButton : ToggleButton, View.IOnClickListener
{
    public MyToggleButton(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) 
        : base(context, attrs)
    {
        SetOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void OnClick(View v)
    {

    }
}
```

Add MyToggleButton to view in the .axml file but do not bind anything to the Click event of the MyToggleButton, than place a break-point(or Trace statement) to the OnClick(View v) method. When you run the program you should hit the break point(or see the trace in the output window of the visual studio).Stop the execution and modify the .axml file to add the binding to Click event with:
local:MvxBind="Click ClickCommand". If you run the solution again the OnClick(View v) wont be executed(the above mentioned break point or trace statemant will not be hit). Is that expected behavior when using MvvmCross? Any explanation will be appreciated.

Uros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the normal Java watcher/listener pattern and it's interaction with MonoDroid.

Only one thing can call `SetOnClickListener` at a time. The C# click event calls `SetOnClickListener` as part of its implementation and it replaces your previous registration.